# How to record and replay the operations on ios?I do not mean the screen recording

Tags: ios, objective-c, record

How can I record the operations on iOS, such as touch, move, select, when they happened, the time, the position of action, the action type will be recorded.And then the record can be replay, the actions would be triggered sequencly .
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi zkz , i think this done via screen capture and Add in a video to show them

Comment: I mean recording the operations, not just the screen view, so it may be different.

Comment: Then you need to store its coordinates information. its subview , parent view , which element move from which coordinate to which coordinate.

Comment: I need record just the action type and the position of the screen, which are enough to replay the operations, so which view was moved is unregarded.

Comment: yes zkz, storing coordinates is the right way.  As per my given answer , you can use SIKULI tools also for making it possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm benefited.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30960/discussion-between-chandan-and-zkz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you this [GestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html):

1. Add a visual tap effect when you press the screen Record yourself
2. using the App on the simulator using a screen capture Add in a video
3. player at the tutorial screen that shows how to use the app

This three action can be done using via AVFoundation framework

**or**

A another way to this is SIKULI tool. You can automate the demo work flows easily http://www.sikuli.org/download.html